# Google Mock - how to name mock functions?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am just getting started with Google Mock.  The [For Dummies](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies) is reasonably easy to follow.

However, I don't understand why the example has

```
class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
 public:
  ...
  MOCK_METHOD0(PenUp, void());
  MOCK_METHOD0(PenDown, void());
  MOCK_METHOD1(Forward, void(int distance));
  MOCK_METHOD1(Turn, void(int degrees));
  MOCK_METHOD2(GoTo, void(int x, int y));
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetX, int());
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetY, int());
};
```

There are multiple MOCK_METHOD0 and multiple MOCK_METHOD1, etc. Functions with similar signatures seem to get the same mock number, but documentation does not mention this, explaining the how & why, and the definitions are identical.  How am I to know what to do?

Comment: On a glimpse, it seems that the number indicates the number of arguments the mocked methods take.

Comment: People voting to close as "primarily opinion-based" question do not understand what the question is.

Comment: Update: In recent versions of gmock, the suffix for the argument is not needed. `MOCK_METHOD` is used for all mocked functions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the [How to Define It](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#how-to-define-it) section, it is explained :

> 3. In the public: section of the child class, write MOCK_METHODn(); (or MOCK_CONST_METHODn(); if you are mocking a const method), where n is the number of the arguments; if you counted wrong, shame on you, and a compiler error will tell you so.